# Calculate Xbee Checksum API Mode C#

Tags: c#, byte, frame, bitwise-operators, operation

I need to calculate a specific checksum for an Xbee Frame. The process is :

> To calculate the check sum you add all bytes of the packet excluding the frame delimiter 7E and the length (the 2nd and 3rd bytes).
>
> 7E 00 0A 01 01 50 01 00 48 65 6C 6C 6F B8
>
> Add these Hex bytes:
>
> 01 + 01 + 50 + 01 + 00 + 48 + 65 + 6C + 6C + 6F = 247
>
> Now take the result of 0x247 and keep only the lowest 8 bits which in this example is 0x47 (the two far right digits). Subtract 0x47 from 0xFF and you get 0xB8 (0xFF - 0x47 = 0xB8). 0xB8 is the checksum for this data packet."

For the moment i've got this code that doesn't work :

```
byte checksum=0x00;
          for(int i=3;i<14+request.Length;i++)
          {
              checksum &= xbeeFrame[i]; //xbeeFrame is the array where are stored the bytes' frame
          }

          checksum &= 0xff;
          Console.WriteLine("The checksum is :"+checksum.ToString("X"));
          xbeeFrame[14 + request.Length] = checksum;
```

The problem is that i don't know how to operate bytes (+ - .. ) in C#. What are the ways to "add" or substract bytes in C# ?

Thank you !!!

Comment: Bytes are an integral type. Msdn has rules about the type (and has an operators list too probably)

Answer (score 0):

If xbeeFrame is an array of bytes than you can just add or subtract the numbers with the operators + and -. But be aware that this datatype can not hold values greater than 0xff = 255. So for example if you do the following:

> result in type byte = 255 + 2 = 1

So a overflow happened.

For your example I think there are a few errors in it. Let me suggest it this way:

```
byte checksum=0x00;
for(int i=3;i<request.Length;i++)
{
    checksum += xbeeFrame[i]; //xbeeFrame is the array where are stored the bytes' frame
}

//checksum &= 0xff; // This one is done implicit through the byte type
checksum = 0xff - checksum; // Noted in your example

Console.WriteLine("The checksum is :"+checksum.ToString("X"));
xbeeFrame[3 + request.Length] = checksum;
```

So you did the loop too often. Like in the description the checksum only has to be calculated for the number of bytes given in the length word which is 0x0A=10.

Comment: Thank a lot for your help ! When i do : checksum = 0xff - checksum;  I get an error so i've to add : checksum = (byte) (0xff - checksum);  Is it still right ?

Comment: Yes should be still right. I see the 0xff is probably not the datatype byte by default. So checksum = (byte)0xff - checksum; should be also possible.

Answer (score 0):

I finally succeed ! Thank you all for your help ! For people how are looking how to calculate checksum ; here's my function :

```
// Calculate Checksum


          int decimalSum = 0;                         // Checksum calculus concept : http://knowledge.digi.com/articles/Knowledge_Base_Article/Calculating-the-Checksum-of-an-API-Packet
          for (int i = 3; i < 14+ request.Length; i++)
          {
              int theElementInInt = Convert.ToInt32(xbeeFrame[i]);                              //We convert each element of the array to int (because it's impossible to make operation that have higher result than 0xFF ( 255 in decimal) in C#. 
              Console.WriteLine(xbeeFrame[i].ToString("X") + "=" + theElementInInt);            // So , the easiest way is to make calculus in decimal domain and switch to hexa when needed

              decimalSum += theElementInInt;                                                    //xbeeFrame is the array where are stored the bytes' frame
          }

          Console.WriteLine("The sum is :" + decimalSum);       

          string decimalSumHexByte = decimalSum.ToString("X");                                  
          Console.WriteLine("The hex value of this sum is :"+decimalSumHexByte+" . I'll only take the two last bytes");  // cf calculus concept for why only the two last bytes
          char[] decimalSumHexByteExploded = decimalSumHexByte.ToCharArray();
          string last2Bytes = decimalSumHexByteExploded[decimalSumHexByteExploded.Length - 2] + "" + decimalSumHexByteExploded[decimalSumHexByteExploded.Length - 1]; 
          Console.WriteLine("The two last bytes are:" + last2Bytes);
          int last2BytesDeciValue = Convert.ToInt32(last2Bytes,16);
          Console.WriteLine("Its decimal value is:" + last2BytesDeciValue);

          int finalIntValue = 255 - last2BytesDeciValue;
          string finalHexValue = finalIntValue.ToString("X");
          if (finalHexValue.Length == 1)                        
          {

              finalHexValue.Insert(0, "0");

          }
          Console.WriteLine("The checksum is :" + finalHexValue);
          finalHexValue.Insert(0, "0x");
          byte finalChecksumByte = Convert.ToByte(finalHexValue, 16);
```

If you need help for that , comment ;) 
Enjoy !